# Two separate menu issues with the MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, apple

I don't know if this has been asked before, but I am struggling with the issue of having two separate menus on Mac. It feels like there is **a serious design flaw** here. For instance, as you can see in the image

[image]

Word has its own menu, and then there is another default menu of Mac. This is the case for all other applications as well

[image]

Jumping from one to the other is quite inconvenient.

Do you have any solution or suggestions for this ?

Thank you very much

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, one is a Menu Bar, the other is a Toolbar. There's no 'fix' for this other than drag the window over to where the menu is.

Historically, Windows has always had the menu bar inside each window. Apple always had it at the top of the screen. As the years have gone on & design philosophies changed, more & more is now being shifted into each window. Note, however, that the Preview toolbar items are also in the menu & all have a key command. Word, less so - they seem to expect you to interact with the mouse & toolbar a lot more.

This is a no-fix situation unless Apple decide to move to a new paradigm.

Comment: Design should be built upon making life easier, and I believe that the necessary paradigm shift will occur for the customer satisfaction.

Comment: It's based on 40 years of legacy design. I doubt it will change any time soon.